# Determining convergence/divergence of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question is to determine convergence/divergence of the following integral:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln x)^3}{1+x^2}dx$$
I think the denominator has nothing to do with solving the question but I just included it because it was in the original question.

I have tried comparing $\ln x$ with $-\cot(\frac{\pi}{2})$ to prove that the original integral is less or equal to $-\infty$ but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, we can ignore the denominator since $\lim_{x\to 0}1+x^2=1$ so by the comparison test your integral converges if and only if $\int_0^1 (\ln x)^3 dx$ converges. For this integral, compare with $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ which converges:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\ln x)^3}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} = \lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x}(\ln x)^3 = 0$$
so $\int_0^1 (\ln x)^3 dx$ converges as well and therefore the original integral converges.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you happen to know how to caclulate $\int_0^\infty \frac{(\ln x)^3}{x^2+1}dx$?

Comment: @delphi You're welcome. Do you mean to determine whether it converges or diverges?

Comment: I have already proved that the $\int_1^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^3}{x^2+1}dx$ converges. I was just wondering what the exact value would be in closed form.

Comment: @delphi For $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{(\ln x)^3}{x^2+1}dx$ use the substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$ and you get it equals $-\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln x)^3}{x^2+1}dx$ so that the total integral equals $0$.